# Angular 5 form component causing Error: 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded '

Tags: angular, forms

Here is my form.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from 
'@angular/forms';

 @Component({
 selector: 'form',
 templateUrl: './form.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
 })
 export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
 formy;
 constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
 this.formy = fb.group({
  name:['enter name here'],
  contact: fb.group({
    email:[],
    phone:[]
  }),
  topics: fb.array([])
  })
 }
}

}
```

The template file looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="formy">
    <input formControlName='name' />
      <div formGroupName='contact'>
        <input formControlName='email' type="text" />
        <input formControlName='phone' type="text" />
      </div>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor='let topic of topics.controls'>
          {{topic.control}}
      </li>
   </ul>
   <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
 <p>Works!</p>
```

The AppModule file looks like this:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Root } from './app.component';
// import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Routing } from './routing.module';
import { AngularMaterial } from './modules/angular-material.module';
// import { Forms } from './modules/forms.module';
import { FormComponent } from './form/form.component';
// import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { Home } from './home/home.component';
import {  ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Root,
    FormComponent,
    Home
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularMaterial,
    // FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    // Forms,
    Routing
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [Root]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The routing works fine when I don't have the  component, in fact it seems to work with everything except for the form component. 
The Error I am receiving looks like this:

> core.js:1601 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>           at FormGroup.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroup._updateValue (forms.js:3764)
>           at FormGroup.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:2600)
>           at new FormGroup (forms.js:3348)
>           at FormBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormBuilder.group (forms.js:6009)
>           at new FormComponent (form.component.ts:12)
>           at createClass (core.js:10156)
>           at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:10041)
>           at createViewNodes (core.js:11263)
>           at callViewAction (core.js:11579)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11498)
>           at FormGroup.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroup._updateValue (forms.js:3764)
>           at FormGroup.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:2600)
>           at new FormGroup (forms.js:3348)
>           at FormBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormBuilder.group (forms.js:6009)
>           at new FormComponent (form.component.ts:12)
>           at createClass (core.js:10156)
>           at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:10041)
>           at createViewNodes (core.js:11263)
>           at callViewAction (core.js:11579)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11498)
>           at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>           at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
>           at zone.js:873
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>           at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4062)
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
>           at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>           at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
>           at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
>           at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)

When I add to the `<form>` element the directive `novalidate` (since the error seemed to be related to that) I receive a different error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>           at createViewNodes (core.js:11228)
>           at callViewAction (core.js:11579)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11498)
>           at createViewNodes (core.js:11291)
>           at callViewAction (core.js:11579)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11498)
>           at createViewNodes (core.js:11291)
>           at callViewAction (core.js:11579)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11498)
>           at createViewNodes (core.js:11291)
>           at createViewNodes (core.js:11228)
>           at callViewAction (core.js:11579)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11498)
>           at createViewNodes (core.js:11291)
>           at callViewAction (core.js:11579)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11498)
>           at createViewNodes (core.js:11291)
>           at callViewAction (core.js:11579)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11498)
>           at createViewNodes (core.js:11291)
>           at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>           at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
>           at zone.js:873
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>           at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4062)
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
>           at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>           at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
>           at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
>           at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
>       defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1601
>       push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1650
>       next @ core.js:4736
>       schedulerFn @ core.js:3721
>       push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:253
>       push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:191
>       push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:129
>       push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:93
>       push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:53
>       push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3713
>       (anonymous) @ core.js:4093
>       push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
>       push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
>       push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:4030
>       onHandleError @ core.js:4093
>       push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:392
>       push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:154
>       _loop_1 @ zone.js:677
>       api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:686
>       drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:602
>       push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:500
>       invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
>       globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566

I read all related posts to this and could not find a solution to this, seemingly this is a very simple form, it is the exact code of a few tutorials, I don't have a deep understanding of forms but really don't get why this isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of your component form.ts which template which uses the HTML5  tag. Since the selector was an HTML tag it was in infinite recursion.

Try to change the selector from "form" to "custom-form" and it will work for sure.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the selector `form`. Change it to `app-form`.

You are utilizing the built in `form` tag inside your own `form` component. This will lead to recursion.

Your custom selector has overridden the built in `form` selector.

Answer (score 0):

The `Root` component is used to bootstrap the application. This should not be in `declarations` array.

Remove it from declarations array:

```
declarations: [
  Root,  ---->  remove this
  FormComponent,
  Home
],
```

Comment: I get the following error when doing that :
"Uncaught Error: Component Root is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module."